# How do i write a query for Profit and loss statement by division in SAP Business One

Tags: sapb1

Please help me with this , This is the query needed by the client where they get profit and loss statement from the crystal by division. So i need to write a query or procedure to retrieve it

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below helps. I used it before

```
    USE [EUROPA_PROD_DB]
    GO

    /****** Object:  View [dbo].[vw_Transactions]    Script Date: 05/04/2012 12:51:24 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Transactions] AS
    SELECT 
    TA.AcctCode,TA.AcctName,TA.GroupMask,TA.Levels,TA.ActType,TA.L1Parent,TA.L2Parent,
    TA.L3Parent,TA.L4Parent,
    TH.TransId,TH.TransType,TH.RefDate PostingDate,TH.DueDate,
    TH.TaxDate,TD.Account,TD.Debit,TD.Credit
    FROM OJDT TH
    INNER JOIN JDT1 TD ON TH.TransId=TD.TransId
    INNER JOIN vw_AccountDetails TA ON TD.Account=TA.AcctCode

    GO

USE [EUROPA_PROD_DB]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vw_AccountDetails]    Script Date: 05/04/2012 12:50:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_AccountDetails]
AS
SELECT TA.AcctCode,TA.AcctName,TA.GroupMask,TA.Levels,TA.ActType,
CASE Levels 
WHEN 1 THEN 
        TA.AcctName
WHEN 2 THEN 
        (SELECT TA1.AcctName FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)
WHEN 3 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)))
WHEN 4 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA3.FatherNum FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum))))
WHEN 5 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA3.FatherNum FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA3.FatherNum FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)))))
ELSE '' END AS L1Parent,
CASE Levels 
WHEN 1 THEN 
    ''
WHEN 2 THEN 
        TA.AcctName
WHEN 3 THEN 
        (SELECT TA1.AcctName FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)
WHEN 4 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)))
WHEN 5 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA3.FatherNum FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum))))
ELSE '' END AS L2Parent,
CASE Levels 
WHEN 1 THEN 
    ''
WHEN 2 THEN 
    ''
WHEN 3 THEN 
        TA.AcctName
WHEN 4 THEN 
        (SELECT TA1.AcctName FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)
WHEN 5 THEN 
        (SELECT TA3.AcctName FROM OACT TA3 WHERE TA3.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA2.FatherNum FROM OACT TA2 WHERE TA2.AcctCode=
        (SELECT TA1.AcctCode FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)))
ELSE '' END AS L3Parent,
CASE Levels
WHEN 1 THEN 
    '' 
WHEN 2 THEN 
    ''
WHEN 3 THEN 
    ''
WHEN 4 THEN 
        TA.AcctName
WHEN 5 THEN 
        (SELECT TA1.AcctName FROM OACT TA1 WHERE TA1.AcctCode=TA.FatherNum)
ELSE '' END AS L4Parent

FROM OACT TA 
WHERE TA.Postable='Y'

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CustomProfit_And_Loss
(
    @BeginDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT L1Parent,L2Parent,Balance,RowOrder
    FROM fn_CustomProfit_And_Loss(@BeginDate,@EndDate)
    order by RowOrder

END

CREATE FUNCTION fn_CustomProfit_And_Loss
(
    @BeginDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS @table TABLE(
    L1Parent VARCHAR(72),
    L2Parent VARCHAR(72),
    Balance MONEY,
    RowOrder INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET @BeginDate=CAST(YEAR(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(2)) +'-'+ CAST(DAY(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(2))
SET @EndDate=CAST(YEAR(@EndDate) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(@EndDate) AS CHAR(2)) +'-'+ CAST(DAY(@EndDate) AS CHAR(2))
--SET @EndDate='2012-12-31'


INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Turnover' THEN 'Income' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Credit-Debit) Balance,
1 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask=4--Income
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

UNION ALL
SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Cost of Sales' THEN 'Cost Of Goods Sold' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Debit-Credit) Balance,
2 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask=5--COGS
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

UNION ALL

SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Operating Costs' THEN 'Expenses' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Debit-Credit) Balance,
3 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask IN(6,71,81)--Expenses
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

RETURN
END
```